# Remote router not responding

Tags: wireless-networking, router, reboot

I have a tp link vn020 router, it doesn't respond and it's ip not showing or working I cant access it nor the internet . it needs to reboot but I can't do that physically because it's 2 miles away from me, I am connected to it via wireless network using modified ddwrt routers something similar to nanostation . is there a way to force reboot the router remotely with a code or any software or something like that?

Comment: If you cannot access it and do not have a remote physical power bar to turn it off, then no. You will have to go there and restart it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.